# SQLAlchemy Sort ColumnCollection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How do I sort a ColumnCollection in SQLAlchemy?

I'm getting a list of columns this way ...

```
listCols = MyTable.__table__.columns
```

Now I want to sort the columns by column name but I really don't want to loose the Column class by converting to a OrderedDict.

Comment: Darn, thanks! I can do a list of columns but I really wanted the column object. I have worked around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listCols = MyTable.__table__.columns
```

returns an `ImmutableColumnCollection` which is not sortable.

However you could use it to create a new [ColumnCollection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnCollection) with the desired order:

```
from sqlalchemy import sql

new_list_cols = sql.expression.ColumnCollection(*sorted(listCols, key=lambda x: x.name))
```

Comment: The new `ColumnCollection` constructor wants the columns as a single named argument (`columns`) instead of as `*args` as of SQLAlchemy 1.4. Because the formatting is messy in comments I will add another answer below

Answer (score 0):

@snakecharmerb your solution works great for 1.3 though `ColumnCollection` has changed with the recent release of SQLAlchemy 1.4.

### SQLAlchemy < 1.4

`ColumnCollection(*sorted(columns, key=lambda c: c.name))`

### SQLAlchemy >= 1.4

`ColumnCollection(columns=[sorted(columns, key=lambda c: c.name)])`

*NOTE*: I haven't tested on 2.x but I'm *guessing* that it wants the same as in 1.4